# What is this usage of be-verbs?

Tags: grammar

> I was in New York.
>   I have been in this armchair for 4 hours.
>   BTS is temporarily in the USA.

Does this usage of be-verbs actually mean 'exist'?

Comment: Welcome! I guess it is nicer to show the effort you'd already made. For example, when I am not sure the usage of a word, I usually look up the definition/explanation and examples on a dictionary or other trusted reference. And then I might ask some question based on that. That would help answerers know what you've understood and what not. Here are some online references that are commonly recognized,Wikipedia, Cambridge Dictionary, Oxford Dictionary, Collins Dictionary, VOA.

Answer (score 2):

It means "exist[s] in a certain location", but you can't just substitute the word "exist" there. It's idiomatic to use a form of "be". See the dictionary definition below:

[American Heritage Dictionary "be"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=BE)

2 a. To occupy a specified position: *The food is on the table.*

Answer (score 1):

It is a linking verb.  It links the prepositional phrase (in New York) 
to the subject, and in doing so it describes the subject.

It is correct to use a noun, adjective or phrase after a linking verb.

> I am a boy
>   I am happy
>   I am in New York

It doesn't really mean "exist". The verb "am" has a function and not really a "meaning". It is part of the grammar. The technical name is a "[copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics))"

The copula in English is very different from that in Korean.